# How can I properly use recv() function to read and store client input

Tags: c++, string, sockets, tcp

```
string readMessage(SOCKET clientSocket)
{
    char buf[4096];
    string storeInfo;
    ZeroMemory(buf, 4096);

    // Wait for the "Enter" key to be pressed
    while (true)
    {
        int bytes = recv(clientSocket, buf, 4096, 0);
        if (bytes == SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            cerr << "Error or invalid input, please try again!" << buf << endl;
            continue; // Restart the loop
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < bytes; i++)
        {
            storeInfo += buf[i];
            if (buf[i] == 13) // 13 is the ASCII code for "Enter"
            {
                cout << " input:-" << storeInfo << "----"  << endl;
                
                ZeroMemory(buf, 4096); storeInfoPtr = &storeInfo;
                return storeInfo; 
                storeInfo = "";

            }
        }
    }
```

I'm using the above code to prompt the client to provide input, then read it using the 'recv()' function, and store the data into a buffer. Then transfer the contents to  string variable called storeInfo.
According to the console output, the program will transfer the content of the buffer to the content of the string, and output it accurately, except for 2 issues.

1. the formatting of the console is not correct, as shown below.
2. the data in the string variable is not recognized at all by using the pointer `storeInfoPtr` to check its contents; initially it will print the correct text, which is just "placeholder," but after that it remains empty

CONSOLE OUTPUT

```
DESKTOP-AFNABTM.lan connected on port 2282
----ut:- √▼ √  √↑ √' ²☺ √♥ ²♥finley 
bad username!
----ut:-fishsticks
bad username!
----ut:-falcon
bad username!
----ut:-falcon
bad username!
----ut:-p3anutbutt3r
bad username!
```

notice the odd appearance of the first line of text, and the presence of unsual shapes and characters. also notice the formatting is completely wrong: the word "input" is cut out and the hyphens that are supposed to appear after the 'storeInput' data are misplaced

TERMINAL INPUT

```
please enter a username:
                         placeholderfinley
bad username
             please enter a username:
                                      fishsticks
bad username
             please enter a username:
                                      falcon
bad username
             please enter a username:
                                      falcon
bad username
             please enter a username:
                                      p3anutbutt3r
bad username
             please enter a username:
```

Notice the 'placeholder' text correctly appears in the first instance, but after updating the variable with some input, it becomes blank

Tried multiple strategies including using a pointer variable to try to store the data in another way and access it in different points of the program

Comment: ASCII 13 (or 0x0d) is commonly called "carriage return". Printing it to a terminal causes the cursor to go back to the start of the line. That at least explains your `input:` being partially overwritten.

Comment: The other question I don't get. You seem to be assigning `storeInfoPtr` the address of a local variable, which becomes garbage once your function exits. But you don't show the code that calls `readMessage` so...

Comment: Tactical note: there's no need for the calls to `ZeroMemory`. You're going to write over at least some of those zeros and the ones you don't write over you don't care about because they are after `bytes`.

Comment: `storeInfo = "";` is totally ineffective because it's after a `return` statement. It will never be reached.

Comment: No need for capital letters or numbers in your usernames?

Comment: @botje well I tried using the 0-126 range and I ran into the same problem

Comment: `std::isalnum` is your friend.

Comment: Opinion: `continue; // Restart the loop` looks weird. An `else` case on the `if` feels more natural.

Comment: @botje thanks man appreciate the help. the reason that I didn't realize there were junk characters in that string was because windows cmd wasn't showing those wierd characters but puTTy was, so I just thought there was an issue with putty. I guess windows terminal is not capable of displaying them.

Comment: Debugging these issues by printing tends to obscure them. Next time use a debugger to look at the bytes or print them as hexadecimal values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a number of problems with your code.

- You are looking for a specific byte, but you are reading whole blocks of data into a byte[] array. If the peer sends more data after the `0x0D` (`'\r'`) byte, you are throwing away the excess data instead of caching it for further processing.
- If `recv()` fails for any error other than `WSAEWOULDBLOCK`, your code will get stuck in an endless loop. It will also get stuck in an endless loop if the peer disconnects gracefully, as `recv()` will return 0 in that case, not `SOCKET_ERROR`, which you are not handling.
- Appending characters to a `std;;string` 1 char at a time is very inefficient, unless you `reserve()` space for it ahead of time.
- You have an external variable named `storeInfoPtr` which you are pointing to the local `storeInfo` before `return`'ing to the caller. However, `storeInfo` will be destroyed upon function exit, leaving `storeInfoPtr` dangling.

Try something more like this instead:

```
string readMessage(SOCKET clientSocket)
{
    char buf[4096], ch;
    int inBuf = 0, numRead;
    string storeInfo;

    // Wait for the "Enter" key to be pressed
    while (true)
    {
        numRead = recv(clientSocket, &ch, 1, 0);
        if (numRead <= 0)
        {
            if (numRead == SOCKET_ERROR)
                cerr << "Read error " << WSAGetLastError() << "!" << endl;
            return ""; or throw an exception
        }

        if (ch == '\r')
        {
            storeInfo.append(buf, inBuf);
            break;
        }
 
        if (inBuf == sizeof(buf))
        {
            storeInfo.append(buf, inBuf);
            inBuf = 0;
        }

        buf[inBuf++] = ch;
    }

    cout << " input:-" << storeInfo << "----"  << endl;
                
    //storeInfoPtr = &storeInfo;
    return storeInfo; 
}
```

---

Note, most systems treat <kbd>Enter</kbd> as `0x0A` (`'\n'`) instead of `0x0D`. If your client doesn't, you should design your protocol so it does. Most common text-based Internet protocols actually send `0x0D 0x0A` instead, regardless of platform.

In which case, try this:

```
string readMessage(SOCKET clientSocket)
{
    char buf[4096], ch;
    int inBuf = 0, numRead;
    string storeInfo;

    // Wait for the "Enter" key to be pressed
    while (true)
    {
        numRead = recv(clientSocket, &ch, 1, 0);
        if (numRead <= 0)
        {
            if (numRead == SOCKET_ERROR)
                cerr << "Read error " << WSAGetLastError() << "!" << endl;
            return ""; or throw an exception
        }

        if (ch == '\n')
        {
            if ((inBuf > 0) && (buf[inBuf-1] == '\r'))
                --inBuf;
            storeInfo.append(buf, inBuf);
            break;
        }
 
        if (inBuf == sizeof(buf))
        {
            if (buf[inBuf-1] == '\r')
            {   
                storeInfo.append(buf, inBuf-1);
                buf[0] = `'\r';
                inBuf = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                storeInfo.append(buf, inBuf);
                inBuf = 0;
            }
        }

        buf[inBuf++] = ch;
    }

    cout << " input:-" << storeInfo << "----"  << endl;
                
    //storeInfoPtr = &storeInfo;
    return storeInfo; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to nitpicky somethings, but you missed a `}` when pasting the function here, we *dont know* (its a pointer to a string) what the `storeInfoPtr` is, not definition in the pasted code, and the line `storeInfo = "";` not only does nothing, but is befour a return, so it does nothing times 2.

```cpp
ZeroMemory(buf, 4096); storeInfoPtr = &storeInfo;
return storeInfo;
storeInfo = "";  // No reason to be here
// this line with nothing annoys me lol
```

Ok, so I was going to complain on the std cause I think its garbage, but thats not the problem *(here)*, I dont know if you are using linux cause this can change.
I "long time ago" *like 3 years*, I learned that linux uses 2 characters to represent a new line, the proper "new line" (`'\n'` or value 10) and the cariage return (the value 13); the "new line" makes the proper new line, but looks like on Linux used to be (I dont know if it stills like this) that just the new line wasnt enough, because it would end up looking like this:

```
this line of text
                 after the new line
```

so the cariage return brings the cursor back to the start.

I dont know why you are using 13 as your confirmation, you could use 10 (`'\n'`) because enter also sends this caracter. If the problem is the new line, just remove the new line like this:

```c
...
if (buf[i] == '\n') // or 10
{
    buf[i] = 0;
    cout << " input:-" << storeInfo << "----"  << endl;
    return storeInfo;
}
...
```

Also, just to add up, like in the comments, why using a std::string? Like, a char[] does everything you need. Assign a pointer to a temporary object has no use, you do alot of stuff after the return, no need to zero the memory, you will write on top of these things, you just need a null character in the end.
If you want I can edit this post, but I just think the way you did this stuff is prety inefficient, I can show another way if you want.

Comment: Linux has always used LF (0x0a) as line ending. Windows is the one that uses CRLF (0x0d 0x0a)

Comment: Also, `std::string` is just fine for storing character data. It frees you from doing manual memory management.

Comment: @Botje std::string is ok, but in THIS example there is no need to make a string + I dont like std stuff.